# Show only current user's products on the frontend in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, author

I need to show only current user's products on the frontend, that is for the user that are logged in, he/she should be only able to view their own products across the site. I tried the code below but this limits access to all the posts and pages which current user didn't create. And I need to limit only for woocommerce products.

```
function shapeSpace_set_only_author($query) {
    global $current_user;
    $query->set('author', $current_user->ID);
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'shapeSpace_set_only_author');
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand your requirement clearly. Do you want to restrict logged in user to see only their own products in Admin area or frontend? If its frontend then it sounds like restricting a seller to buy only his own products (that too, if he is logged in; if not he can buy any product from other sellers too). Is that really the business requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **dedicated** `woocommerce_product_query` action hook that will restrict the product displayed to:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'shapeSpace_set_only_author', 20, 2 );
function shapeSpace_set_only_author ( $q, $query ) {
    if( is_admin() ) return;

    global $current_user;
    $q->set('author', $current_user->ID);
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme).

Tested and works

Answer (score 1):

Almost there, you just need to specify that you want to alter the query only for products.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'modify_query_show_current_user_products' );

function modify_query_show_current_user_products( $query ) {
    global $current_user;

    if( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && isset( $query->query_vars['wc_query'] ) && $query->query_vars['wc_query'] == 'product_query' ) {
        $query->set('author', $current_user->ID);
    }
}
```